# Get the highest nesting level of an object array with subarrays - javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say we have an object array like this in javascript

```
myArray= [
            {
                title: 'category1',
                items: [
                    {
                        title: 'title1',
                        exclude: false,
                        id: 22,
                        include: false,
                        entries: 6,
                        items: [
                            {
                                title: 'title12',
                                exclude: false,
                                id: 122,
                                include: false,
                                entries: 6,
                            },
                            {
                                title: 'title22',
                                exclude: false,
                                id: 152,
                                include: false,
                                entries: 66,
                            }
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'title2',
                        exclude: false,
                        id: 66,
                        include: false,
                        entries: 666,
                        items: [],
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                title: 'category2',
                items: [
                    {
                        title: 'title3',
                        exclude: false,
                        id: 12,
                        include: false,
                        entries: 66,
                        items: [],
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'title4',
                        exclude: false,
                        id: 15,
                        include: false,
                        entries: 6666,
                        items: [],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ];
```

What I would like to achieve is to get the number of highest nesting level of arrays. In this example we have 'title: category1' which has a subarray 'title: title1' which once again has a subarray. So we have 3 levels starting from the first to the last. I assume there must be a better way than doing nested loops recursively for each item and see which one has the most levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this works for you =)

```
function deep(array, depth=1){
    return Math.max(...array.map((e)=>{
        return ((e.items && e.items.length>0 )?deep(e.items, depth+1) : depth);
    }),0)
}
```

But you should post your best attempt at solving the task next time

Comment: solid solution. Thanks